# Is there a way to have an infinite loop using PageView in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to have an infinite loop using **PageView** in Flutter? For example if my PageView has 5 pages, after swiping to page 5, I would be able to swipe again in the same direction to get to Page 1.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

By default, `PageView.builder` is infinite in flutter. Unless you provide an `itemCount`.

The following will print page from 0 to 4 infinitely

```
final controller = new PageController(initialPage: 999);
 ...

new PageView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new Center(
          child: new Text('${index % 5}'),
        );
      },
)
```

Comment: Ohh I thought itemCount is required, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks Remi, I was searching for a solution to stop the infinite scroll of my pageview.

Comment: But isn't this a hack? Ok, maybe noone will scroll 999 pages to the left, but IF he does: there is an end. So it's more like a "half-line" as far as I know. Still, good to know there is a way to give an initial page to start with.

Comment: will this continuously eat up memory as the pages go on? or will previous pages be released from memory?

Comment: @MobileMon they will be released from memory unless you specifically tell the framework to keep them.

Comment: The initial page starts at 999, it's not how many pages exist just where to start. Meaning that you can go all the way to 80000+ without any issue. @DominikusK.

Comment: That is the direction I am with you @Matthew. But what with users scrolling back to the pages 998, 997, .., 1, 0, -1??

Comment: This solution allows scrolling only in one direction, but If for example I have 3 images and start from image 1 I want to scroll backwards and get to image 3 instantly

Comment: @RémiRousselet I want to set `initialPage` to 1. how can I do it?

Comment: The builder is called only for those children that are actually visible. So it's efficient

Comment: This hack has an effect on performance, you can't set any value for initialPage, for example if you replace 999 with 999999999999999 the app becomes unusable.

Answer (score 21):

If you have a list of pre-defined Widgets, you can achieve continuous scrolling using:

```
return PageView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _children[index % _children.length];
  },
  controller: pageController,
);
```

Comment: Wondering how this is on memory. Will it continuously create memory and never release it?

Comment: this won't work, cause pageController won't go lower than zero without any hacks.

Comment: It did work for me. It's not the best way to go about it, but it works :))

Answer (score 7):

I've found a good solution using this lib
https://pub.dev/packages/infinity_page_view

Just import the lib and use `InfinityPageView` instead of `PageView`

```
InfinityPageView(
  controller: infinityPageController,
  itemCount: colorList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
      color: colorList[index];
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 4):

> You can achieve infinite
> scrolling using PageView builder, without giving value to itemCount there will be infinite pages, you just have to maintain the page index which will be painted on screen.

```
PageView.builder(
  controller: _pageController,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  onPageChanged: (index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index % _walkthroughSlides.length;
    });
  },
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _walkthroughSlides[index % _walkthroughSlides.length];
  },
)
```

Comment: This should be the correct accepted answer, Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The answer mentioned above will take more memory and probably that is redundancy and when you are on the first child you can't go the last one by scrolling in reverse direction

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class InfiniteScroll extends StatefulWidget{
  final List<Widget> children;
  InfiniteScroll({this.children});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _InfiniteScrollState();
  }
}

class _InfiniteScrollState extends State<InfiniteScroll>{
  List<Widget> children;
  ScrollController s;
  int _pos;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pos=1;
    children = [widget.children[widget.children.length - 1]];
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.children.length; ++i) {
      children.add(widget.children[i]);
    }
    if (widget.children.length > 1) {
      children.add(children[1]);
    }
    s = PageController();
    super.initState();
     WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_){
          s.jumpTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
        });
 
  }
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return PageView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: s,
      onPageChanged: (int i) {
        setState(() {
          _pos=i+1;
        });
        if (i == children.length - 1) {
          Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
            s.jumpTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
          });
          setState(() {
          _pos=1;
        });

        } else if (i == 0) {
          Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
            s.jumpTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (children.length - 2));
          });
          setState(() {
            _pos=children.length-2;
          });
        }
        
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return children[index];
      },
      itemCount: children.length,
    );
  }
}
```

and now you can use it as

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test1/Widgets/infinite_scroll.dart';


class CoursesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return 
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: 
              InfiniteScroll(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Center(child: Text("1",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 50),),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: Center(child: Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 50),),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(child: Text("3",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 50),),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(child: Text("4",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 50),),),
                  ),
                ],
              )
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: ugly solution, setState calls twice per page swipe, magic numbers in code

Comment: Did you run the code.and I think init state will run only first time when you initialize the state.so no way init state will be called two time per swipe build will be called and it going to call it only one time

Comment: did you run your code? I don't think so, because in this case you should know setState executes twice every time when you swipe to last or first page
moreover if you try to swipe fast you will get "lag" and no swipe every time when last or first page is on screen

Comment: It's a little ugly, but I think it's a good idea. I will try to catch the touch-end event and trigger the `s.jumpTo`

Answer (score 0):

It's work without controller. You need comment prop itemCount & repce index like bellow.

```dart
PageView.builder(
  onPageChanged: (v) {
    setState(() => _currentImage = v % images.length);
  },
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  // itemCount: images.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
    return CustomImageNetwork(
      width: imageSize,
      height: imageSize,
      image: images[i % images.length] ?? '',
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Used extention beside remi solution

```
extension ListX<E> on List {
  E loop(int index) => this[index % length];
}

class _CarouselWidgetState extends State<CarouselWidget> {
  late final List<Widget> children;
  late final PageController controller;
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    children = widget.children;
    controller = PageController(initialPage: 100);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      // itemCount: children.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, pagePosition) {
        return children.loop(pagePosition)
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "OverScroll notifier" and PageController controller.jumpToPage() to change the current page to the last or the first page depending on the edge we "overscrolled".

```
class CarousselView extends StatefulWidget {
const CarousselView({super.key});

@override
State<CarousselView> createState() => _CarousselViewState();
}

class _CarousselViewState extends State<CarousselView>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
 int _index = 1;

 TabController? controller;
 late PageController _controller;
 String message = "";

  @override
 void initState() {
 controller = TabController(
  length: 6,
  vsync: this,
   );
  _controller = PageController();
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Stack(
   children: [
    NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
      onNotification: ((notification) {
        print("Oversrolled");
        setState(() {
          _controller.jumpToPage(_index == 0 ? 5 : 0);
        });
        return true;
      }),
      child: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 6,
        controller: _controller,
        onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() {
          controller!.index = index;
          _index = index;
        }),
        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
          return Card(
            elevation: 6,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Card ${i}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: TabPageSelector(
        indicatorSize: 6.0,
        controller: controller,
         ),
        )
       ],
     );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the loop page view  https://pub.dev/packages/loop_page_view
it's a pretty straightforward plugin

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loop_page_view/loop_page_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Loop Page View Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: LoopPageView.builder(
            itemCount: 2,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('$index'),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final controller = new PageController(initialPage: children.length*999);

PageView.builder(
  controller: controller,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Text('${index % children.length}'),
    );
  },
```

)