# Flutter make Perspective Page View infinite loop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I implemented a `perspective_page_view` like [this](https://github.com/letsdoit07/flutter_perspective_pageview/blob/master/lib/main.dart). I updated the code to the new Flutter Version and everything is working fine.

The thing is that I would like that `PageView` to have an **infinite loop**.

I tried multiple different solutions I found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161719/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-infinite-loop-using-pageview-in-flutter) question but non of them worked. They all messed up the perspective in my case.

I feel like this should be possible, but I can not come up with a solution. Happy for every help! Let me know if you need any more info!

**Minimal Producable Example:**

My `Scaffold`:

```
class ProjectsViewState extends State<ProjectsView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late PageViewHolder holder;

  late PageController _controller;
  double fraction = 0.50;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    holder = PageViewHolder(value: 2.0);
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 2, viewportFraction: fraction);
    _controller.addListener(() {
      holder.setValue(_controller.page);
    });
  }

  int currentPage = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<PageViewHolder>.value(
          value: holder,
          child: Flexible(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentPage = value;
                });
              },
              itemCount: projectsCounter,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ProjectsGalleryView(
                  number: index.toDouble(),
                  fraction: fraction,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the `pageView`:

```
class ProjectsGalleryView extends StatefulWidget {
  final double number;
  final double fraction;

  const ProjectsGalleryView(
      {super.key, required this.number, required this.fraction});

  @override
  State<ProjectsGalleryView> createState() => _ProjectsGalleryViewState();
}

class _ProjectsGalleryViewState extends State<ProjectsGalleryView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double value = Provider.of<PageViewHolder>(context).value;
    double diff = (widget.number - value);

    //Matrix for Elements
    final Matrix4 pvMatrix = Matrix4.identity()
      ..setEntry(3, 3, 1 / 0.8) // Increasing Scale by 80%
      // ..setEntry(1, 1, widget.fraction) // Changing Scale Along Y Axis
      ..setEntry(3, 0, 0.003 * -diff); // Changing Perspective Along X Axis

    return Transform(
      transform: pvMatrix,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (diff <= 1.0 && diff >= -1.0) ...[
            AnimatedOpacity(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              opacity: 1 - diff.abs(),
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 15,
                  vertical: 20,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'A Text with animated opacity',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include sample snippet

Comment: [here](https://github.com/letsdoit07/flutter_perspective_pageview/blob/master/lib/main.dart) is the sample code @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example so that your question is self-contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want the scroll to be smooth on the left side as well. You just have to set arbitrarily `LARGE NUMBER` as a starting point so that it feels `INFINITE` (large number like 9 trillion). However, it won't scroll indefinitely.

1. set some large number (ex: `const largeInt = 9223372036854;`)
2. modify your `initState` like below

---

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  holder = PageViewHolder(value: largeInt.toDouble());
  _controller = PageController(
    initialPage: largeInt,
    viewportFraction: fraction,
  );
  _controller.addListener(() {
    holder.setValue(_controller.page);
  });
}
```

---

And the Full Code for the `ProjectView`

```
const largeInt = 9223372036854;

class ProjectsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProjectsView({super.key});

  @override
  ProjectsViewState createState() => ProjectsViewState();
}

class ProjectsViewState extends State<ProjectsView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late PageViewHolder holder;

  late PageController _controller;
  double fraction = 0.50;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    holder = PageViewHolder(value: largeInt.toDouble());
    _controller = PageController(
      initialPage: largeInt,
      viewportFraction: fraction,
    );
    _controller.addListener(() {
      holder.setValue(_controller.page);
    });
  }

  int _currentPage = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<PageViewHolder>.value(
            value: holder,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: PageView.builder(
                    controller: _controller,
                    onPageChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() => _currentPage = value);
                    },
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ProjectsGalleryView(
                        number: index.toDouble(),
                        fraction: fraction,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

// Previous answer

TL;DR It's not a perfect solution, but to scroll infinitely on the **left side as well**, add `jumpToPage` inside the `_controller.addListener`

First, do not include `itemCount` in `Pageview.builder` or set it to `null`.

However, Even though you set `itemCount` to `null`, it still ends when the `index` is `0`.

So, in the `initState` add following after initializing `PageController`.

```
_controller.addListener(() {
  holder.setValue(_controller.page);
  final page = _controller.page;
  if (page == null) return;
  if (page < 2.01 && page > 1.99) {
    _controller.jumpToPage(10);
  }
});
```

by adding `_controller.jumpToPage(10)` when `_controller.page` is in betweem 1.99 and 2.01, `_pageController` will set the page to 10 again.

The reason I added this in the `_controller.addListener` is that if you put that in `onPageChanged`, it will stutter real bad since the returned `value` is `int`.

However, even though I used the double to minimize the impact, it will still kinda stutter a bit when scrolling really fast, and if its extremely fast, there is a chance that it will not work. However, this will always work for normal page by page scrolling.

The full code for your `ProjectView Widget`.

```
class ProjectsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProjectsView({super.key});

  @override
  ProjectsViewState createState() => ProjectsViewState();
}

class ProjectsViewState extends State<ProjectsView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late PageViewHolder holder;

  late PageController _controller;
  double fraction = 0.50;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    holder = PageViewHolder(value: 2.0);
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 2, viewportFraction: fraction);
    _controller.addListener(() {
      holder.setValue(_controller.page);
      final page = _controller.page;
      if (page == null) return;
      if (page < 2.01 && page > 1.99) {
        _controller.jumpToPage(10);
      }
    });
  }

  int currentPage = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<PageViewHolder>.value(
          value: holder,
          child: Flexible(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                setState(() => currentPage = value);
              },
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ProjectsGalleryView(
                  number: index.toDouble(),
                  fraction: fraction,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: appreciate the help, but like you said, not a perfect solution :D and its throwing errors for me in some cases as well.. For this project, the solution should be as smooth as possible

Comment: well, I modified my answer.
If that is what you want, then there is no other way then starting the page with arbitrarily large number.

Comment: did you try the new answer? It is messing up the `transform` on init. But after scrolling the first time, it looks good...

Comment: Yes and I have added the full code for the `ProjectViewState` Widget.
Your code had a problem, and it's not because of the `initState` with large number.
It's because you have `Flexible` right inside the `SafeArea`. So I just wrapped `Flexible` with `Column` and everything is fine.

Comment: that was it. working as expected now :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the accepted answer in the related question you linked also working?

simply not providing the `itemCount: projectsCounter` resulted in the following:

[image]

is this what you're after?

code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'PageViewHolder.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Perspective PageView',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ProjectsView(),
    );
  }
}

class ProjectsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProjectsView({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProjectsView> createState() => ProjectsViewState();
}

class ProjectsViewState extends State<ProjectsView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late PageViewHolder holder;

  late PageController _controller;
  double fraction = 0.50;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    holder = PageViewHolder(value: 2.0);
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 2, viewportFraction: fraction);
    _controller.addListener(() {
      holder.setValue(_controller.page);
    });
  }

  int currentPage = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<PageViewHolder>.value(
          value: holder,
          child: Flexible(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentPage = value;
                });
              },
              // itemCount: projectsCounter,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ProjectsGalleryView(
                  number: index.toDouble(),
                  fraction: fraction,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProjectsGalleryView extends StatefulWidget {
  final double number;
  final double fraction;

  const ProjectsGalleryView(
      {super.key, required this.number, required this.fraction});

  @override
  State<ProjectsGalleryView> createState() => _ProjectsGalleryViewState();
}

class _ProjectsGalleryViewState extends State<ProjectsGalleryView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double value = Provider.of<PageViewHolder>(context).value;
    double diff = (widget.number - value);

    //Matrix for Elements
    final Matrix4 pvMatrix = Matrix4.identity()
      ..setEntry(3, 3, 1 / 0.8) // Increasing Scale by 80%
      // ..setEntry(1, 1, widget.fraction) // Changing Scale Along Y Axis
      ..setEntry(3, 0, 0.003 * -diff); // Changing Perspective Along X Axis

    return Transform(
      transform: pvMatrix,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (diff <= 1.0 && diff >= -1.0) ...[
            AnimatedOpacity(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              opacity: 1 - diff.abs(),
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 15,
                  vertical: 20,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'A Text with animated opacity',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:

sorry, dont have enough karma to comment but:
yes i can scroll infinitely (more then 3 times lol), i have rebuilt a new flutter app with newer versions and v2 embeddings, i can create and link you the repo if you want

Comment: what??? Can you actually swipe to the left more than 3 items?

Comment: I mean, can you swipe to the left right from the beginning?

Comment: Yep, that's possible, left or right as far as I want

Comment: not working for me.. I got it working with @HW Kim solution. But thanks for your help :)